# How to restart terminated threads using ScheduledThreadpoolExecutor in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I want to have a thread pool that is maintained to a constant number of threads. I want all the threads that are dying due to an exception or terminating gracefully, spawn up their exact replica to maintain the number of threads.

I've tried the following code to expect that it'll continuously keep printing 1-2-3-4-1-2-3-4.... in a loop however it stops after the first execution.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Testing {
    @Test
    public void tet() {
        ScheduledExecutorService poolExecutor =
                new CustomExecutor(4);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
            poolExecutor.execute(new Task(i));
        }
    }

}

class Task implements Runnable {

    int x;

    Task(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(x);
        if (true) {
            System.out.println("throwing exception " + x);
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }
}

class CustomExecutor extends ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor {

    public CustomExecutor(int corePoolSize) {
        super(corePoolSize);
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
        this.execute(r);
    }
}
```

I changed the code to the following as suggested in the answer ::

```
    public class Testing {
    @Test
    public void tet() {
        ScheduledExecutorService poolExecutor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(4);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
            poolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Task(i), 0, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }
    }
}
class Task extends Thread {

    int x;

    Task(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

The output is not repeating. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Why don't just catch it

Comment: That is always an option. I'm testing out the afterExecute function.

Comment: The fixed thread pool executor doesn't lose threads when an exception occurs, so it isn't clear what you want.

Comment: DO NOT restart threads!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need restart the dead thread mannully, when new task is submitted, the executor will check if it is necessary to create new thread.

In this case, if you expect the task keep running after the exception, you can catch and handle it.

Also, if you just `execute` the task, it will only be executed once. You should `schedule` them if you expect continous execution as well as `wait` for  termination:

```
@Test
public void tet() {
    ScheduledExecutorService poolExecutor =
            new CustomExecutor(4);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        poolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Task(i), 0, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
    try {
        poolExecutor.awaitTermination(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited the question. I'm tried the way you mentioned, to schedule at a fixed rate, however the output was the same. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I want to get the scheduler to work even without an exception. Is there a way for that?

Comment: As far as I know, No. You have to catch this execption `somewhere`.

Comment: This means that if the thread does not throw an exception, it won't be scheduled again? That seems odd!

Comment: I've tried not throwing an error as well. It still won't work. Edited question for clarity.

Comment: @psychorama Junit will not wait for all tasks to finish. You have to call `awaitTermination` to block current thread. Otherwise even if is executed again, you can not see the result since the test method has exited. Or you can create a `public static void main` method indead a `Test` method. See my update.